# Listing GitLab Repositories name using GitLab api

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I want to list only GitLab repositories name using GitLab API.

i tried command `curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=*************"`

it is listing all merge requests, issues and also repository names.

How can i list only the repository names?

Comment: Hi, there is this endpoint available "GET /projects/:id/repository/tree". It's represent that you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Igor mentioned the Gitlab API does not let you to limit the response to a single field.

I would recommend combining the original API call with the `jq` command.
This will enable parsing of the returned json

```
curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=*************" | jq '.[].name'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to limit the response to a single field only via API, but there's `simple` option to return minimal set of fields:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects

`curl "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects?simple=true&private_token=*************"` would return something like:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "description": null,
    "default_branch": "master",
    "ssh_url_to_repo": "git@example.com:diaspora/diaspora-client.git",
    "http_url_to_repo": "http://example.com/diaspora/diaspora-client.git",
    "web_url": "http://example.com/diaspora/diaspora-client",
    "readme_url": "http://example.com/diaspora/diaspora-client/blob/master/README.md",
    "tag_list": [ //deprecated, use `topics` instead
      "example",
      "disapora client"
    ],
    "topics": [
      "example",
      "disapora client"
    ],
    "name": "Diaspora Client",
    "name_with_namespace": "Diaspora / Diaspora Client",
    "path": "diaspora-client",
    "path_with_namespace": "diaspora/diaspora-client",
    "created_at": "2013-09-30T13:46:02Z",
    "last_activity_at": "2013-09-30T13:46:02Z",
    "forks_count": 0,
    "avatar_url": "http://example.com/uploads/project/avatar/4/uploads/avatar.png",
    "star_count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "description": null,
    "default_branch": "master",
...
```